# How can i use _module.less in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, css

I'm writing a custom module and i need to add styles. So i'm trying to follow magento's way with using _module.less file.
i've created a file `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less`. When i change this file, i see, that `grunt watch` see those changes and recompiles my styles. But changes from my _module.less file never gets into result files. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, i've found an answer. I worked on the admin part of a module before. So it somehow generated a code without frontend part. So what i did to get it work:

- Disable module with clear content: `php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_Module --clear-static-content`
- Clear cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- Enable module back with clear content `php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Module --clear-static-content`

Comment: This worked for me! Accept this answer (:

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Allready tried. More than that: i'm in developer mode - so, as i know, i don't need do deploy static content